# Using scala-library.jar in an Android project throws error: Library cannot be dexed

Tags: android, scala, dex

I have a very simple Android project set up that uses:

- Several custom Scala JARs that are going to perform some functionality for my app
- scala-library.jar version 2.9.1 final so the Scala jars can run

However, whenever I try to launch the app, I get errors saying that the scala-library cannot be Dexed because it is too large.

Googling shows that this is a problem, but I am unsure how to fix it. Some say Proguard is the answer, but I don't know how to do that.

I don't currently use Ant for any build management, just Eclipse tools.

Any help or tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ProGuard prior to dexing the standard library.

There is an sbt plugin for Scala Android projects available here: https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/

The Getting Started guide is quite detailed: https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/wiki/getting-started

This plugin automatically uses ProGuard.

If you want to use ProGuard manually yourself, check out: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html