# A library in Scala -- use in Android

Tags: java, android, scala, jvm, dalvik

I'm pretty new in Android development. Since android is based on virtual machine called Dalvik and it's different from Java Virtual Machine, is it possible to to create a library in Scala and use it in Android?

The answer is pretty straightforward ("yes") for me, but nevertheless I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! But there are some know how's. You should use ProGuard prior to dexing the standard scala libraries.

Start here: https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/
Details here:  https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/wiki/getting-started

If you encounter problems refer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215718/using-scala-library-jar-in-an-android-project-throws-error-library-cannot-be-de) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066516/android-scala-preinstalled-scala-libraries-disabled-proguard-throws-classn)**

.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get this. can't I just write a library (.jar file) in Scala and use it in Android?

Comment: Yes, I dont have any examples with me for using an scala jar , i can just point you to `https://github.com/bkase/android-scala-example` as an example but that is to set up for writing scala android apps, but my answer above essentially imports jar's written in scala into android and hence I would think your requirement is defintely possible with some know hows like dexing the right way.